# laravel 4 sentry 2 how to change password and rehash

Tags: php, laravel, cartalyst-sentry

In my app there's a view that allows the logged in user to enter a new password. How am I to hash the new password? Using native Laravel `Auth` I would just

```
Hash::make($input['password']);
```

is it the same for `Sentry 2`? If it is, after performing a reset and updating the user table I get a `WrongPasswordException` so I'm assuming the hash methods are different. If Sentry has it's own hash method, I sure can't find it.

**Update:** Apparently [this method](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/users/reset-password) will work the same way and auto-save the user record, the docs just don't point that out.

Comment: It appears that there is a Mutator on `UserModel::$password` which automatically hashes the password according to the Hasher set in the config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update the user using the Sentry methods, it will automatically hash the password as `Sentry::getUserProvider()->create();` do.

```
try
    {
        // Find the user using the user id
        $user = Sentry::findUserById(1);

        // Update the user details
        $user->email = 'john.doe@example.com';
        $user->first_name = 'John';

        // Update the user
        if ($user->save())
        {
            // User information was updated
        }
        else
        {
            // User information was not updated
        }
    }
    catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserExistsException $e)
    {
        echo 'User with this login already exists.';
    }
    catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotFoundException $e)
    {
        echo 'User was not found.';
    }
```

Comment: Dang I just figured this out on my own a second ago. The docs should mention something about that logic.

Comment: @JaredEitnier I fell the same as you, the docs of Sentry lacks of it :/